# how to use like operator for complex query in sqlite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Hi all i have the following table called student in SQLite database.

this is my table structure

```
id       name
-----------------------

"3"  "Babu Qw"  
"2"  "Ganesh Babu"  
"1"  "Murali  Abb"  
"4"  "ganesh1 Babu"             
"5"  "hari murali"              
"10" "Abbash abc"
```

name field is combined by first name and last name. for example "Babu Qw"  Babu is the first name and Qw is the last name its separated by a space.

and name is the input field where 'ba' is my input parameter.(**Ex .. name like 'ba'**)

now i want to fetch the records whatever name **(first name or last name )** starts with 'ba' not by any middle character.

output would be:

```
id       name
-----------------------

"3"  "Babu Qw"  
"2"  "Ganesh Babu"  
"4"  "ganesh1 Babu"
```

here "Abbash abc" (first name Abbash or last name abc does not starts with ba) so that "Abbash abc" not listed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
select id, name
from table
where name like 'Ba%' or name like '% Ba%'
```

Comment: Thanks i did not use name col after the OR.
select * from contactdetail where name like '% ba%' or 'ba%'. i did the mistake here.

Comment: Yep, that's not possible for now, maybe in the future ^^

Answer (score 1):

Can you use REGEXP with SQLite?
Something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name REGEXP('^ba.*') OR name REGEXP('^.* ba.*');
```

Note : I'm not really at Regular Expression so this one may be false, or you may even do that in just one.
Well you see the idea.

Comment: @aF. Yes :) I'm a specialist when it comes to kill flies with a Bazooka

Comment: You can use regular expressions with SQLite just fine, but you don't then get to use any indices to optimize the query. *Some* LIKE queries can take advantage of indices (particularly those where you're looking for a prefix).