# android how to select data from database using matching

Tags: android

im getting data from database which match any prefex   how to add % on bothside of variable? below is my query  i want to add   '"+School_name+"' to this   '%"+School_name+"%'   how to do that?

```
        Cursor mCursor3 = db.selectQuery("SELECT * FROM uss_school sch LEFT JOIN uss_school_to_level sl ON  sch.school_id = sl.school_id LEFT JOIN uss_level l ON sl.level_id = l.level_id WHERE sch.name like '"+School_name+"'");
```

Comment: i want to get any data from database which match any string  i know use % but how to set in query help me

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603080/how-to-use-like-operator-for-complex-query-in-sqlite and http://zetcode.com/db/sqlite/expressions/

Comment: i want to do like  WHERE sch.name like '"+"%"+School_name+"%"+"'"  check it is  correct????

Comment: Try  WHERE sch.name like '%"+School_name+"%'"